# append files that are defined with certain characters in their file names python

Tags: python, if-statement, filenames

i am writing a python script to extract only the files that I want to read in a folder.
I defined the places of characters in file names first. Then try to call them by a def().
The example filenames are like:
`***_41*11_12.dat` or
`***_41*11_5.dat` or
`***_83*22_5.dat`

The script below shows me still all the files in the folder.
How can I specify the file names exactly and call and add them to a list?
Thanks in advance.

The code is:

```
def plot(folder_path, xx= str(41), zz=str(11), a=str(12)):
       usefiles=[]
   
       for filepath in glob.iglob(folder_path):
          mod = filepath[5:7] #define mod characters in file name
          station= filepath[8:10] #define stations characters 
          iter1 = filepath[11] # place of the iteration number if value between 1-9.
          iter2 = filepath[11:13] #place of the iteration number when it is between 10-30
          if mod== xx:
             if station == zz:
                 if len(a) == 1:
                     iter1= a
                 else:
                     iter2=a
         usefiles.append(filepath)
```

Comment: In the example, are you trying to match _only_ `_4111_12.dat`? Or all files that end it `_4111_12.dat`?

Comment: You assign some variable `iter1` and `iter2` but never use them? Also you loop and append all values here `usefiles.append(filepath)`, this line is not inside any condition, what do you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to match all the files that are beginning with ´´´_41´´´ and ending with ´´´12 (.dat)´´´ @JohnnyMopp

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, ´´´iter1´´´ and ´´´iter2´´´ are  in an if condition. I want to use iter1 ´´´if len(a) == 1´´´, otherwise, use ´´´iter2´´´. How can I make them use with the last if condition for ´´´a´´´. If the ´´´usefiles.aappend(filepath)´´´ is in the condtion it writes all the data several times.

Comment: You can use a pattern with `iglob`. Try adding a pattern to the path like `for filepath in glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder_path, "_41*12.dat")):`

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp. It is also useful. But  I found the point.  `iter` for `a` value should be defined only once and as `[11:-4]`. Then the lenght doesn't matter. It reads all  characters between.